# How can I integrate PayPal for Dinar currency used in Kuwait?

Tags: magento, paypal

I want to integrate PayPal in magento. I have set base currency and default currency as Dinar.  I have also set Dollar as allowed currency. But when I reach the checkout process there is no  payment method options. But when I change all the currency as Dollar, PayPal method starts displaying on checkout process.

What I want to know is that can I set Dinar in all options in currency setup options? 
Or I am doing anything wrong in this process?

Please suggest me some ideas regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dinar is not an accepted currency in PayPal, hence it's not shown as a payment option.